# Objective-C class implements C++ interface

Tags: c++, objective-c, interface

Have a way of an Objective-C class implements a C++ interface?

---

For example, I have a interface in C++ IInter:

```
class IInter {
public:
    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
}
```

I have a C++ class and it needs a IInter instance:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(IInter delegate);
}
```

and I need use the MyClass instance on Objective-C class, how I do this?

```
@interface MyObjcClass : NSObject <UIInter> ... ??
```

Thanks all!

Comment: @BoPersson ok I'll add details.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to mix C++ class in an `objective C` project the best idea seems to wrap your C++ types and functions with `Objective-C` equivalents. This is well explained in this [article](http://philjordan.eu/article/mixing-objective-c-c++-and-objective-c++) and [here](http://robnapier.net/blog/wrapping-cppfinal-edition-759). Note that if you are using `clang` you can declare your C++ `ivar` in your `class extension`, this is probably the cleanest way.

Comment: thanks, very good article, but if have a way of implements directly will be more sample, if dont have other way i use a wrap like that article explained.

Comment: again i think the wrapper is the way to go there is no simple way.